# Whether the current Tensorflow Federated can be deployed across multiple physical machines?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am wondering whether there is a way to run [tff](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated) across multiple distributed physical devices (e.g., virtual machines). I haven’t figured out how to deploy this so far, and the tutorial shows this version is for simulation only.

Answer (score 0):

As of release `0.5.0` TFF only supports simulation.